# PARSE_DATE not working in FORMAT() in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have this query (simplified):

```
FOR TABLE IN (
  SELECT
    tables FROM project.dataset.table) 
DO
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
  FORMAT("""
  SELECT
    PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', event_date)
    event_timestamp, 
    event_name, 
    user_pseudo_id, 
    user_first_touch_timestamp, 
    device.category, 
    device.mobile_brand_name, 
    device.mobile_model_name, 
    device.web_info.hostname, 
    geo.country, 
    geo.city, 
    traffic_source.name, 
    traffic_source.medium, 
    traffic_source.source
  FROM
    %s""", TABLE.tables);
END FOR;
```

I get the following error:

**Query error: Invalid format specifier character "Y" in FORMAT string**

The query works fine without:

```
PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', event_date)
```

As soon as this line is put in, it fails with the above error. The percent marks have their own meaning inside FORMAT(), however I am wondering how to make this work?

I've tried escaping and using raw strings but it is didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should escape **%** in your dynamic query with additional **%**,
Use below

```sql
PARSE_DATE('%%Y%%m%%d', event_date)
```