# SQL: Creating columns based on row data for each user

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a survey and I want to do aggregations based on the demographic data that come with their responses. However, the survey doesn't automatically format the data for that purpose.

For example, let's say we have a three question survey:

1. What is your Eye Color?  (Demographic Question)
2. What is your Hair Color?  (Demographic Question)
3. What is your Salary?

The table below is the raw survey data.

| UserID | Question | Answer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Eye_Color | Brown |
| 1 | Hair_Color | Black |
| 1 | Salary | $100 |
| 2 | Eye_Color | Blue |
| 2 | Hair_Color | Blond |
| 2 | Salary | $150 |

I want format my data to eventually perform group by's any question that uses "color" . Thus, I need to **dynamically** create columns on all questions that have "color" in them.

| UserID | Question | Answer | Eye_Color | Hair_Color |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Salary | $100 | Brown | Black |
| 2 | Salary | $150 | Blue | Blond |

What SQL query can I use to do this dynamically? I thought about windowing, but I'm sure there is more to it. Also, I am using Google BigQuery for the database.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider below using a dynamic SQL which *left-join* demographic information to *question&answer*s  for each user.

*Note* that I've added one more question for `UserID 1` in your survey data.

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE responses AS
  SELECT 1 UserID, 'Eye_Color' Question, 'Brown' Answer UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 UserID, 'Hair_Color' Question, 'Black' Answer UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 UserID, 'Salary' Question, '$100' Answer UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 UserID, 'Car' Question, 'QM5' Answer UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 UserID, 'Eye_Color' Question, 'Blue' Answer UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 UserID, 'Hair_Color' Question, 'Blond' Answer UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 UserID, 'Salary' Question, '$150' Answer;

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT("""
SELECT * FROM (
  -- Questions and answers except demographic informations
  SELECT * FROM responses WHERE Question NOT LIKE '%%Color%%'
) LEFT JOIN (
  -- Demographic informations
  SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM responses
  ) PIVOT (ANY_VALUE(Answer) FOR Question IN ('%s'))
) USING (UserID);
""", (SELECT STRING_AGG(DISTINCT Question, "','") FROM responses WHERE Question LIKE '%Color%'));
```

**Query results**

[image]

**See Also :**

- `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/procedural-language#execute_immediate
- `%%Color%%` - [PARSE_DATE not working in FORMAT() in BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73292980/parse-date-not-working-in-format-in-bigquery)