# Create columns from the distinct values of a column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to make a query that is based on the distinct value of a specific table column. I'm using the BigQuery service from Google Cloud.

Here's how my table presents itself:

| Date | Type | Location | Name | Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-07 | Type1 | Location1 | Name1 | Group1 |
| 2022-07 | Type2 | Location1 | Name2 | Group2 |
| 2022-08 | Type1 | Location2 | Name3 | Group2 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

I want to count the the amount of each `Type` for each specific location. The problem is that there's a large amount of different `Type` and `Location`.

Here's what I would normally do:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT Location,
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Type = Type1 THEN Name END),
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Type = Type2 THEN Name END),
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Type = Type3 THEN Name END),
... #same thing for all types
FROM `table`
WHERE Group = "Group1" OR Group = "Group2"
GROUP BY Location
```

I was wondering if there was a way to get all the values from the `Type` column and iterate in a way to create column automatically without having to manually input it myself in order to get something like this:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT Location,
iterate on Type[n]
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Type = Type[n] THEN Name END)
FROM `table`
WHERE Group = "Group1" OR Group = "Group2"
GROUP BY Location
```

To obtain:

| Location | Type1 | Type2 | Type3 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Location1 | n_Type1 | n_Type2 | n_Type3 | ... |
| Location2 | n_Type1 | n_Type2 | n_Type3 | ... |
| Location3 | n_Type1 | n_Type2 | n_Type3 | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

I've seen the `PIVOT` function in other posts that can be used to achieve the result I want but I'm struggling to put it into place, especially since some `Type` have spaces, meaning I need to use a replace in order for them to be valid column names.

Here's my SQL query using `PIVOT` (not working):

```sql
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE(SELECT '''
SELECT Location, REPLACE(Type, " ", "_") AS Type,
COUNT(Distinct Name) AS Nbr
FROM `table`
WHERE Group LIKE "Group1" 
OR Group LIKE "Group2"
GROUP BY Location,  Type
PIVOT (any_value(Result) for Type in (''' || string_agg(distinct "'" || REPLACE(Type, " ", "_") || "'") || 
"))"
FROM `table`
)
```

Comment: *since some Type have spaces* --> `type1` and `type 1` should be considered same ?

Comment: No they're different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seems to want *aggregate* and *pivot* query.

**1st step : aggregation**

```sql
SELECT Location, Type, COUNT(Name) Count 
  FROM sample_table 
 GROUP BY 1, 2;
```

This returns a stacked(unpivoted) result like below

[image]

**2nd step : pivoting**

Once you pivot the previous result, you'll get the result you want.

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT Location, Type, COUNT(Name) Count 
    FROM sample_table 
   GROUP BY 1, 2
) PIVOT (ANY_VALUE(Count) FOR Type IN ('Type1', 'Type2', 'Type3'));
```

[image]

**3rd step: dynamic query**

> iterate on Type[n]
> COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Type = Type[n] THEN Name END)

if `n` is a large number, you should consider a dynamic query. you can refer to the following links for this.

- [Change direction of table in BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72869053/change-direction-of-table-in-bigquery)
- [Bigquery - Best way to transpose rows into multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74327529/bigquery-best-way-to-transpose-rows-into-multiple-columns)

---

**Updated**

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE `sample_table` AS
  SELECT '2022-07' Date, 'Type1' Type, 'Location1' Location, 'Name1' Name, 'Group1' `Group` UNION ALL
  SELECT '2022-07' Date, 'Type2' Type, 'Location1' Location, 'Name2' Name, 'Group2' `Group` UNION ALL
  SELECT '2022-08' Date, 'Type 1' Type, 'Location2' Location, 'Name3' Name, 'Group2' `Group`
;

-- before using a dynamic sql
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT Location, REPLACE(Type, " ", "_") AS Type,
         COUNT(Distinct Name) AS Nbr
    FROM `sample_table`
   WHERE `Group` LIKE "Group1" OR `Group` LIKE "Group2"
   GROUP BY Location, Type
)  PIVOT (ANY_VALUE(Nbr) FOR Type IN ('Type1', 'Type2', 'Type_1'));

-- using a dynamic sql
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT("""
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT Location, REPLACE(Type, " ", "_") AS Type,
         COUNT(Distinct Name) AS Nbr
    FROM `sample_table`
   WHERE `Group` LIKE "Group1" OR `Group` LIKE "Group2"
   GROUP BY Location, Type
)  PIVOT (ANY_VALUE(Nbr) FOR Type IN ('%s'))
""", (SELECT STRING_AGG(DISTINCT REPLACE(Type, ' ', '_'), "','")
        FROM `sample_table`
       WHERE `Group` LIKE 'Group1' OR `Group` LIKE 'Group2'
     ));
```

Comment: I'm trying to go through those steps, but i'm struggling with the pivot command itself, as you said it needs to be dynamic, and in order to so, I have to use the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE() command. I'm guessing the problem is the syntax of my Pivot query, but i don't see the mistake yet.

Comment: I checked your answer, I'm getting an error: 
"Invalid format specifier character "V" in FORMAT string"
I see what you're trying to do with this answer, and i think it's the right approach, it's probably a mistake on my side

Comment: If you run the query as it is, it will succeed, so take another look at your code and also check the data you're testing.  and if you still get an error, let me know with the actual query you're testing.

Comment: by any change, you're using an `%` in your query, for example `LIKE 'Group%'` or something ?

Comment: Yes i am in order to filter the groups of my choosing, in both where conditions

Comment: If so, you need to escape `%` with additional `%` in *format()* function,   see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75397329/sql-creating-columns-based-on-row-data-for-each-user/75398305#75398305

Comment: Great, escaping with an additionnal `%` did the trick, thank you for your help